Give an example of $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ such that $T^4=-I$.
The below exercise comes from Linear Algebra Done Right, 4th Edition, by Sheldon Axler. It is in Section 5A, exercise number 31.

Give an example of $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ such that $T^4=-I$.

Couple notes on notation:

By $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$, we mean the vector space of linear operators defined on $\mathbb{R^2}$.


By $T^4$, we mean the composition of $T$ four times. That is, for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$, we have
$$
T^4(x,y) = T(T(T(T(x,y))))
$$


By $I$, we mean the identity operator such that $I(x,y)=(x,y)$.

What I've tried:
I have spent probably a couple hours thinking of such a $T$. When I came up with defining $T$ by $T(x,y) = (-|x|, -|y|)$, I was ecstatic, until I realized that $T$ is NOT linear.
So please, could someone give me a hint? Do I need to think about eigenvalues somehow? Maybe think about a basis?

Think of rotations

Your $T^4\ne-I$.  E.g., $T(-1,-1)=(-1,-1)$ and $T^4(-1,-1)=(-1,-1)\ne-1(-1,-1)$

@J.W.Tanner oh, so a double whammy with that $T$.

There is an "encoding" of complex numbers as $2\times 2$ real matrices: $a+bi\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} a & b \ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$. Hence if you can solve the equation $x^4=-1$ over $\mathbb C$, you can find a $2\times 2$ real matrix solving the same equation. This method works more generally for equations that are more difficult to be interpreted geometrically.

Hint for a geometric method The map $-I$ geometrically represents a reflection through the origin, or just as well as a rotation by $\pi$. So for any positive integer $n$, the (say, anticlockwise) rotation $R$ by $\frac\pi n$ has the property that applying it $n$ times gives a rotation by $n \cdot \frac\pi n = \pi$, that is, $R^n = -I$.
Hint for an algebraic method If you'd like to avoid ad hoc appeals to geometric intuition, here's a strictly algebraic approach: Since $T^4 = -I$, for some (in fact, any) nonzero ${\bf x} \in \Bbb R^2$, $T{\bf x}$ is not a multiple of ${\bf x}$ (why?). So, $({\bf x}, T{\bf x})$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$, and with respect to this basis the matrix representation of $T$ has the form
$$[T] = \pmatrix{0&a\\1&b} .$$
Now, expanding $[T]^4 = [T^4] = [-I]$ and comparing entries gives the manageable polynomial system
\begin{align}
a b^2 +   a^2   + 1 &= 0 \\
a b^3 + 2 a^2 b     &= 0 \\
  b^3 + 2 a   b     &= 0 \\
  b^4 + 3 a   b^2 + a^2 + 1 &= 0 \\
\end{align}

 The solutions are $(a, b) = (-1, \pm \sqrt 2)$, giving $$[T] = \pmatrix{0 & -1 \\ 1 & \pm \sqrt 2} .$$ Using our basis to choose coordinates $(x, y)$ gives explicit maps $T \in \mathcal L(\Bbb R^2)$, $$T(x, y) = (y, -x \pm \sqrt 2 y).$$ Remark These matrices are the companion matrices of the polynomials $x^2 \mp \sqrt 2 x + 1$, whose roots are the primitive $8$th roots of unity, i.e., the $4$th roots of $-1$.) Appealing to the Jordan canonical form shows that every map $T \in \mathcal L(\Bbb R^2)$ satisfying $T^4 = -I$ is conjugate to this one (for a fixed choice of $\pm$), including the rotation by $\frac\pi4$.


When you say "$T{\bf x}$ is not a multiple of ${\bf x}$", that means $T$ cannot have any eigenvalues, right?
And to answer your "why?", is it because if it did have an eigenvalue, say $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then $T^4{\bf x} = \lambda^4 {\bf x}$, but no such $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\lambda^4 = -1$?

It's sufficient for the argument that there is some nonzero vector that isn't an eigenvector of $T$, and that's true for every linear transformation that isn't a scalar multiple of the Identity. But it's true in this case that any $T$ satisfying the condition has no (real) eigenvalues, and your argument shows why.

Hint:
Think of rotations.
$-I$ represents a $180^\circ$ rotation.
Can you think of rotations that become a $180^\circ$ rotation when repeated four times?

Should I be thinking of a movement of $\pi / 4$ four times from the initial point?

Yes, that is one example

A rotation by any odd multiple of $\pi/4$ works

Building off of what J.W. Tanner stated in their answer, one could cite that $T$ need only be a member of the set $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. Specifically, $T$ may be a 2-dimensional rotation matrix which rotates a vector $45^\circ$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ radians upon multiplication (e.g. $T=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$ where $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$). One could also instead let $T$ be the first 8th root of unity or $\sqrt i$ (which happens to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i$). However, these answers are analogous if one lets $1$ be represented by the identity matrix $I\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ and $i$ be represented by the matrix $J=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.
If daring enough, however, one could likely assume $T$ is a diagonalizable matrix and solve the equation $4\ln(T)=4P\ln(D)P^{-1}=\ln(-I)$ (although this admittedly appears dubious upon second look).
Edit: I realize I never made explicit the way in which the above formulation would actually be useful. Observe:
Let $T,I\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\forall m,p\in\mathbb{N},(\forall A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\forall B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p},(AI=A)\wedge(IB=B))$ given some integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$$T^4=-I\implies\ln(T^4)=\ln(-I)\iff4\ln(T)=\begin{pmatrix}\ln(-1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(-1)\end{pmatrix}$$
Suppose $T=PDP^{-1}$ for $P\in\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and diagonal $D$.
$$\begin{align}
4\ln(T)=4\ln(PDP^{-1})=4P\ln(D)P^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}\ln(-1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(-1)\end{pmatrix}\\
4P\ln\begin{pmatrix}d_1\\&\ddots\\&&d_n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}i\pi\\&\ddots\\&&i\pi\end{pmatrix}\\
4P\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}&=i\pi I\\
4P\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)\end{pmatrix}&=i\pi P\\
P\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)\end{pmatrix}&=\frac{\pi}{4}iP\\
P^{-1}P\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)\end{pmatrix}&=P^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}iP\right)\\
\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)\end{pmatrix}&=\frac{\pi}{4}iI\\
\begin{pmatrix}\ln(d_1)-\frac{\pi}{4}i\\&\ddots\\&&\ln(d_n)-\frac{\pi}{4}i\end{pmatrix}\mathbf{v}&=\mathbf{0}
\end{align}$$
Note that the very last equation indicates the solution for the diagonal matrix $D$ is none other than an eigenvalue problem, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the vector upon which the transformation is applied.

How did you come up with $T=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$, and know it would work? Does it have to do with a trigonometric identity? If so, could you point me to it?

Never mind, I found it on wiki, thank you for your answer!
